# Org-mode: protect emphasis

Tags: emacs, org-mode

How could I protect emphasis like italics or code within Emacs org-mode
when I have things like

```
/cologne/dome/
```

or

```
=<pre language="python">=
```

?

Comment: I do not understand you question. Maybe you could explain what you get now and what you want to do?

Comment: The question as such isn't clear.  What are you trying to protect in the above examples (What is the output and what would you want the output to be)?

Comment: Problem: I want to put something italics which includes the markers for italics (= slash) or put something to code which includes the markers for code (= equal sign). Is there I way I can protect these?

Answer (score 7):

The following org-block demonstrates which parts work by default and which need a small amount of work-around to work.

The following was created using `Org-mode version 7.8.03 (release_7.8.03.321.gaac1c)`.  If you're using an older version it is possible that the behaviour is slightly different.

See [Literal Examples](http://orgmode.org/manual/Literal-examples.html) and [Monospace](http://orgmode.org/manual/Emphasis-and-monospace.html) in the Org-Manual for full details

ORG

```
* Italics
  - Your example simply works\\
    /cologne/dome/
  - It also works if your /example had / spaces within it/
  - It will only fail if / your /have spaces on one end or the other /
* Code
  Code blocks can be delimited in multiple ways:
 ** Inline formatting
    - Using ~ for verbatim text works\\
      ~<pre language="python">~
    - ~ renders the same as = for blocks =test= ~test~
 ** Code Blocks
    - Single-line blocks
      : <pre language="python">
    - Multi-line blocks
      #+BEGIN_EXAMPLE
        asdf
      #+END_EXAMPLE
```

HTML Export

```html
<div id="outline-container-1" class="outline-2">
<h2 id="sec-1"><span class="section-number-2">1</span> Italics</h2>
<div class="outline-text-2" id="text-1">

<ul>
<li>Your example simply works<br/>
  <i>cologne/dome</i>
</li>
<li>It also works if your <i>example had / spaces within it</i>
</li>
<li>It will only fail if / your /have spaces on one end or the other /
</li>
</ul>

</div>

</div>

<div id="outline-container-2" class="outline-2">
<h2 id="sec-2"><span class="section-number-2">2</span> Code</h2>
<div class="outline-text-2" id="text-2">

<p>Code blocks can be delimited in multiple ways:
</p>
</div>

<div id="outline-container-2-1" class="outline-3">
<h3 id="sec-2-1"><span class="section-number-3">2.1</span> Inline formatting</h3>
<div class="outline-text-3" id="text-2-1">

<ul>
<li>Using ~ for verbatim text works<br/>
  <code>&lt;pre language="python"&gt;</code>
</li>
<li>~ renders the same as = for blocks <code>test</code> <code>test</code>
</li>
</ul>

</div>

</div>

<div id="outline-container-2-2" class="outline-3">
<h3 id="sec-2-2"><span class="section-number-3">2.2</span> Code Blocks</h3>
<div class="outline-text-3" id="text-2-2">

<ul>
<li>Single-line blocks
<pre class="example">
&lt;pre language="python"&gt;
</pre>

</li>
<li>Multi-line blocks



<pre class="example">asdf
</pre>

</li>
</ul>
```

LaTeX Export

```latex
\section{Italics}
\label{sec-1}

\begin{itemize}
\item Your example simply works\\
\emph{cologne/dome}
\item It also works if your \emph{example had / spaces within it}
\item It will only fail if / your /have spaces on one end or the other /
\end{itemize}
\section{Code}
\label{sec-2}

Code blocks can be delimited in multiple ways:
\subsection{Inline formatting}
\label{sec-2-1}

\begin{itemize}
\item Using \~{} for verbatim text works\\
\verb~<pre language="python">~
\item \~{} renders the same as = for blocks \texttt{test} \verb~test~
\end{itemize}
\subsection{Code Blocks}
\label{sec-2-2}

\begin{itemize}
\item Single-line blocks
\begin{verbatim}
   <pre language="python">
\end{verbatim}
\item Multi-line blocks

\begin{verbatim}
asdf
\end{verbatim}
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: As mentioned ~verbatim~ worked but it broke on quotes for me, single and double.  This [link](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2010-04/msg00330.html) helped by adding the U200B (ZERO WIDTH SPACE) character before the closing ~.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to output the original `/cologne/dome/`, but not `<i>cologne/dome</i>`, right?

Two ways:

1. set `#+OPTIONS: *:nil` to turn off all emphasis symbols
2. modify `org-emphasis-alist`, remove the relevant items

I also asked a similar question here: [How do I escape slash in org-mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15324852/how-to-escape-slash-in-org-mode)