# How do I escape slash in org-mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Take `foo /bar/ baz` as example, when exported to HTML, it becomes `foo <i>bar</i> baz`, now I want to export it with the original style `foo /bar/ baz`, how to achieve this ? I have tried `foo \/bar\/ baz`, but the output becomes `foo \/bar\/ baz`.

I know this is an easy question, I have googled a lot, but only find this one: [Escape pipe-character in org-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144862/escape-pipe-character-in-org-mode), the answer says slash escaping works fine, but for me, it seems not fine.

---

edit:

After searching org mode mailing list, I find a discussion and solution here: http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/50743

There are two ways to do this:

1. set option `#+OPTIONS: *:nil` to turn off all emphasis symbols
2. modify variable `org-emphasis-alist`, remove relevant content

For me, the first solution is acceptable, and also it is simple.

Comment: I appreciate the answers people are giving, but they only illustrate that orgmode really needs a proper escaping mechanism.  I've run into many situations like this with markup in orgmode, they're not always solveable with workarounds like this.

Comment: For example, a newline breaks `/italics/` processing, so AFAIK I have to put whole paragraphs on one line if I want them italicized.

Answer (score 7):

Put a zero-width space (U+200B; insert in Emacs using Ctrl-x 8 RET 200B RET) between the whitespace and the forward slash.

org-mode text

```
What do we see?
- /foo/
- ​/foo/
```

with a zero-width space inserted just before the first forward slash on the second "foo" line (not visible, because it has zero width) yields the following HTML after exporting:

```
<div id="content">
<h1 class="title">What do we see?</h1>

<ul>
<li><i>foo</i>
</li>
<li>​/foo/
</li>
</ul>

</div>
```

The zero-width space is exported, too, and ends up between the `<li>` and the `/foo/` where you'd expect it.

Answer (score 1):

If you can tolerate a space between the slashes, `foo / bar / bas` will export with literal slashes. Alternatively you can make the whole string verbatim with `=foo /bar/ baz=`.

I suspect that neither of these is exactly what you want, but they can be done easily and may be good enough.

**EDIT** 
If you need slashes for a URL you should use orgmode link syntax, e.g., `[[http://foo/bar.baz]]`.

Comment: Hi @lsta, thanks for your answer, you are right, the two you mentioned are not I wanted. Since the slashes are part of a URI, like `href="/blog/post1/"`, so extra spaces and verbatim string are not proper for this situation.

Comment: Hi @KelvinHu, I've edited the answer to address the url question.

Comment: Hi @lsta, in fact it is not a complete URL like `http://example.com/blog/post1/`, it is just a URI, like `/blog/post1/`, so I cannot use link syntax. However, thanks for your answer, I have figured out how to solve this problem, please see the "edit" part of my question.

Answer (score 1):

(I'll re-post [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144862/escape-pipe-character-in-org-mode) here for the sake of completeness...)

You could also format the relevant text as *verbatim* or *code*:

> Text in the code and verbatim string is not processed for Org mode
>   specific syntax; it is exported verbatim.

So you might try something like `=foo | bar=` (code) or `foo ~|~ bar` (verbatim).  It does change the output format, though.

Answer (score 0):

Placing a zero width space (\u200B) before and after the character you want to escape does the trick.

I did a function that can insert the character you want between these two spaces.

```lisp
(defun org-insert-literal-character (c)
  "Insert a literal character at point."
  (interactive "cWhat character?")
  (insert ?\u200B c ?\u200B))

(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c i l") 'org-insert-literal-character)
```

Given an emphasized sentence:

[Ready to insert the slash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rr8g.png)

Move the point to where you want to insert the character and press 'C-c i l' and '/':

[Slash inserted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ADIF.png)

Also, here is an example of an org html generated website using this:

[Website with emphasized slash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmvZA.png)